# How do I center an icon in the leading attribute of a list tile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter app need to center the icon in the "leading" attribute of this list tile. I have already tried wrapping the icon in Center(), which centers it in the middle of the tile instead of the leading space. Here is my Dart code and screenshot:

```
Widget _contentListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _listItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: _listItems[index].icon,
          title: Text(
            _listItems[index].title,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          subtitle:
              Text(_listItems[index].subtitle, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          onTap: () {
            dataEdited(index);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Either use create a custom list widget like ListTile or title property for icon and wrap it with center  title : Center(child:Icon(Icons.person)), You can also use horizontal content padding.

Comment: 2023: titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Widget _contentListView() {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _listItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: <Widget>[
                           _listItems[index].icon,
                       ],
               ),//add here
              title: Text(
                _listItems[index].title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              subtitle:
                  Text(_listItems[index].subtitle, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
              onTap: () {
                dataEdited(index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: I get an exception relevant to the ListView saying "'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 545 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true."